# Java Builder Design Pattern Redundant Field Declaration in Class and its Builder

Tags: java, builder-pattern

The classic Builder Pattern requires fields to be declared in the class-to-be-built and the exact same fields to be declared in the builder class.  This can lead to problems when there are many fields and, during refactoring, the field types are not kept in sync.  Here's an example of what I mean (I borrowed this code sample from an article by Joshua Block):

```
// Builder Pattern
public class NutritionFacts {
    private final int servingSize;
    private final int servings;
    private final int calories;
    private final int fat;
    private final int sodium;
    private final int carbohydrate;

    public static class Builder {
        private int servingSize   = 0;
        private int servings      = 0;
        private int calories      = 0;
        private int fat           = 0;
        private int carbohydrate  = 0;
        private int sodium        = 0;

        public Builder servingSize(int val)
            { servingSize = val;   return this; }
        public Builder servings(int val)
            { servings = val;      return this; }
        public Builder calories(int val)
            { calories = val;      return this; }
        public Builder fat(int val)
            { fat = val;           return this; }
        public Builder carbohydrate(int val)
            { carbohydrate = val;  return this; }
        public Builder sodium(int val)
            { sodium = val;        return this; }

        public NutritionFacts build() {
            return new NutritionFacts(this);
        }
    }

    private NutritionFacts(Builder builder) {
        servingSize  = builder.servingSize;
        servings     = builder.servings;
        calories     = builder.calories;
        fat          = builder.fat;
        sodium       = builder.sodium;
        carbohydrate = builder.carbohydrate;
    }
}
```

Now let's assume that `servingSize` needs to be changed from `int` to `long` and that this change is done in `NutritonFacts` but, by accident, not also done in the static `Builder`.

Admittedly less problematic is the number of fields.  `NutritionFacts` has 6 fields and, therefore, so does `Builder`.  What if there were 20 or 100 fields?  Duplicating them all in `NutritionFacts` and `Builder` would be  real pain.  Is there a better way so that all the duplication and potential for type-syncing errors can be avoided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `NutritionFacts` object to store your Builder's state:

```
// Builder Pattern
public class NutritionFacts {
    private final int servingSize;
    private final int servings;
    private final int calories;
    private final int fat;
    private final int sodium;
    private final int carbohydrate;

    public static class Builder {
        private NutritionFacts state = new NutritionFacts(0,0,0,0,0,0);

        public Builder servingSize(int val) { 
            state = new NutritionFacts(val, state.servings, state.calories, state.fat, state.sodium, state.carbohydrate);
            return this;
        }
        [...]

        public NutritionFacts build() {
            return new NutritionFacts(this);
        }
    }

    private NutritionFacts(Builder builder) {
        servingSize  = builder.state.servingSize;
        servings     = builder.state.servings;
        calories     = builder.state.calories;
        fat          = builder.state.fat;
        sodium       = builder.state.sodium;
        carbohydrate = builder.state.carbohydrate;
    }

    private NutritionFacts(int servingSize, int servings, int calories, int fat, int sodium, int carbohydrate) {
        this.servingSize  = servingSize;
        this.servings     = servings;
        this.calories     = calories;
        this.fat          = fat;
        this.sodium       = sodium;
        this.carbohydrate = carbohydrate;
    }
}
```

As `NutritionFacts` is immutable, this will require constructing a new state object for every change, which might or might not be worth it.

It will be easier if you can make `NutritionFacts`'s internal state mutual, but use private setters - making the objects immutable by definition instead of by the `final` keyword:

```
// Builder Pattern
public class NutritionFacts {
    private int servingSize = 0;
    private int servings = 0;
    private int calories = 0;
    private int fat = 0;
    private int sodium = 0;
    private int carbohydrate = 0;

    public static class Builder {
        private NutritionFacts state = new NutritionFacts();

        public Builder servingSize(int val) { 
            state.servingSize = val;
            return this;
        }
        public Builder servings(int val) { 
            state.servings = val;
            return this;
        }
        [...]

        public NutritionFacts build() {
            return new NutritionFacts(this);
        }
    }

    private NutritionFacts(Builder builder) {
        servingSize  = builder.state.servingSize;
        servings     = builder.state.servings;
        calories     = builder.state.calories;
        fat          = builder.state.fat;
        sodium       = builder.state.sodium;
        carbohydrate = builder.state.carbohydrate;
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand that the solution you initially posted (but edited away) was problematic in that the introduction of a no-argument constructor for `NutritionFacts` caused compiler errors due to all the fields being declared `final`.  But why do they need to be declared `final`?  `NutritionFacts` has no setters and calling the `Builder`'s `build()` method a second time only creates another instance of `NutritionFacts` rather than modify the fields of the original.  I think your initial solution, but without the `final` modifiers, is the way to go.  Yes?

Comment: Yes... just change `new NutritionFacts(0,0,0,0,0,0);` to `new NutritionFacts();`

Comment: I've edited my answer to include code for both options. I would also prefer the "immutable by definition" approach, because it makes the setters more compact. If you don't have a requirement for `final` state, then yes - that is the way to go.

Comment: The consumer of the `NutritionFacts` object (pun most definitely intended!) cannot modify the object once instantiated.  It is true that a programmer can modify the class to modify a field due to its no-longer-declared-final status, but that's an acceptable trade-off.  Thanks for this.  It's very simple and clean.

Answer (score 2):

You can enhance **classic builder pattern** with the **step builder pattern** in order to build objects with a no brain interface, easy to use, impossible to get wrong. See this [post](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/building-smart-builders.html) for more detail.